# Inserting EXEC result and string into table

Tags: sql-server, r, database, stored-procedures, binaryfiles

I'm trying to store a binary image in a database; the image is a plot generated in R of Microsoft's sample "Adventure works" database. The following example code works fine:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Plots
EXEC   sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'R'
     ,@script = N'  df <- inputDataSet; #read input data
                image_file = tempfile(); #create a temporary file
                jpeg(filename = image_file, width=500, height=500); #create a JPEG graphic device
                hist(df$Ages); #plot the histogram
                dev.off(); #dev.off returns the number and name of the new active device (after the specified device has been shut down). (device = graphical device)
                #file() opens a file, in this case the image. rb = read binary
                #readBin() reads binary data. what = described the mode of the data. In this case, it''s raw data. n = maximum number of records to read.
                #data.frame converts the data to a data frame, which is required as output by SQL Server. The result is written to the OutputDataset variable.
                OutputDataset <- data.frame(data=readBin(file(image_file,"rb"),what=raw(),n=1e6));
                    '
    ,@input_data_1 = N'SELECT Ages = DATEDIFF(YEAR,[BirthDate],GETDATE())
                        FROM [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[DimCustomer];'
    ,@input_data_1_name = N'inputDataSet'
    ,@output_data_1_name = N'OutputDataset'
```

However, the `Plots` table only has one column, `plot`. If I alter it so that now each plot has a `name` column associated with it, how would I alter the insert query?

I've tried

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Plots(plot, name)
VALUES(
    (EXEC   sp_execute_external_script
          @language = N'R'
         ,@script = N'  df <- inputDataSet; #read input data
                    image_file = tempfile(); #create a temporary file
                    jpeg(filename = image_file, width=500, height=500); #create a JPEG graphic device
                    hist(df$Ages); #plot the histogram
                    dev.off(); #dev.off returns the number and name of the new active device (after the specified device has been shut down). (device = graphical device)
                    #file() opens a file, in this case the image. rb = read binary
                    #readBin() reads binary data. what = described the mode of the data. In this case, it''s raw data. n = maximum number of records to read.
                    #data.frame converts the data to a data frame, which is required as output by SQL Server. The result is written to the OutputDataset variable.
                    OutputDataset <- data.frame(data=readBin(file(image_file,"rb"),what=raw(),n=1e6));
                        '
        ,@input_data_1 = N'SELECT Ages = DATEDIFF(YEAR,[BirthDate],GETDATE())
                            FROM [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[DimCustomer];'
        ,@input_data_1_name = N'inputDataSet'
        ,@output_data_1_name = N'OutputDataset')
    , 'testname'
)
```

with pretty much every combination of parentheses around the `EXEC`, order of columns etc. (I'm sure it'll need some parentheses, as without them it confuses the line `, 'testname'` as another parameter being passed to the stored procedure), but I just can't avoid a syntax error!